# How do I build a numpy array from a generator?

Tags: python, numpy, generator

How can I build a numpy array out of a generator object?

Let me illustrate the problem:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> def gimme():
...   for x in xrange(10):
...     yield x
...
>>> gimme()
<generator object at 0x28a1758>
>>> list(gimme())
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> numpy.array(xrange(10))
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> numpy.array(gimme())
array(<generator object at 0x28a1758>, dtype=object)
>>> numpy.array(list(gimme()))
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

In this instance, `gimme()` is the generator whose output I'd like to turn into an array. However, the array constructor does not iterate over the generator, it simply stores the generator itself. The behaviour I desire is that from `numpy.array(list(gimme()))`, but I don't want to pay the memory overhead of having the intermediate list and the final array in memory at the same time. Is there a more space-efficient way?

Comment: This is an interesting issue. I came accross this by `from numpy import *; print any(False for i in range(1))` - which shadows the built-in [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) and produces the opposite result (as I know now).

Comment: @moooeeeep that's terrible. if `numpy` can't (or doesn't want to) to treat generators as Python does, at least it should raise an exception when it receives a generator as an argument.

Comment: @max I stepped on exact same mine. Apparently this was raised [on the NumPy list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.numeric.general/47681/focus=47702) (and [earlier](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.numeric.general/13197)) concluding that this will not be changed to raise exception and one should always use namespaces.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Numpy arrays require their length to be set explicitly at creation time, unlike python lists. This is necessary so that space for each item can be consecutively allocated in memory. Consecutive allocation is the key feature of numpy arrays: this combined with native code implementation let operations on them execute much quicker than regular lists.

Keeping this in mind, it is technically impossible to take a generator object and turn it into an array unless you either:

1. can predict how many elements it will yield when run:

   ```
   my_array = numpy.empty(predict_length())
   for i, el in enumerate(gimme()): my_array[i] = el
   ```
2. are willing to store its elements in an intermediate list :

   ```
   my_array = numpy.array(list(gimme()))
   ```
3. can make two identical generators, run through the first one to find the total length, initialize the array, and then run through the generator again to find each element:

   ```
   length = sum(1 for el in gimme())
   my_array = numpy.empty(length)
   for i, el in enumerate(gimme()): my_array[i] = el
   ```

**1** is probably what you're looking for. **2** is space inefficient, and **3** is time inefficient (you have to go through the generator twice).

Comment: The builtin `array.array` is a contiguous non-linked list, and you can simply `array.array('f', generator)`. To say say it's impossible is misleading. It's just dynamic allocation.

Comment: Why numpy.array doesn't do the memory allocation the same way as the builtin array.array, as Cuadue says. What is the tradeof? I ask because there is contiguous allocated memory in both examples. Or not?

Comment: numpy assumes its array sizes to not change. It relies heavily on different views of the same chunk of memory, so allowing arrays to be expanded and reallocated would require an additional layer of indirection to enable views, for example.

Comment: Using empty is a bit faster. Since you are going to initialize the values any way, no need to do this twice.

Comment: See also @dhill's answer below which is faster than 1.

Answer (score 250):

One google behind this stackoverflow result, I found that there is a [`numpy.fromiter(data, dtype, count)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html). The default `count=-1` takes all elements from the iterable. It requires a `dtype` to be set explicitly. In my case, this worked:

`numpy.fromiter(something.generate(from_this_input), float)`

Comment: how would you apply this to the question? `numpy.fromiter(gimme(), float, count=-1)` does not work. What does `something` stand for?

Comment: something.generate is just the name of the generator

Comment: @Matthias009 `numpy.fromiter(gimme(), float, count=-1)` works for me.

Comment: A thread explaining why `fromiter` only works on 1D arrays: http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2007-August/028898.html.

Comment: fwiw, `count=-1` does not need to be specified, as it is the default.

Comment: @askewchan Interestingly, `numpy` couldn't/didn't set a default `dtype=None`. If they did, it would have the same interface as `pd.array`. They could infer dtype within the function by retrieving the first element outside of the loop iterattion, and then set the array `dtype` to that first element's type like `dtype = dtype or type(iterable_first_element)`

Comment: If you know the length of the iterable beforehand, specify the `count` to improve performance. This way it allocates the memory before filling it with values rather than resizing on demand (see the documentation of `numpy.fromiter`)

Comment: This doesn't work for object arrays. It raises an value error saying "cannot create object arrays from iterator."

Answer (score 24):

While you can create a 1D array from a generator with `numpy.fromiter()`, you can create an N-D array from a generator with `numpy.stack`:

```
>>> mygen = (np.ones((5, 3)) for _ in range(10))
>>> x = numpy.stack(mygen)
>>> x.shape
(10, 5, 3)
```

It also works for 1D arrays:

```
>>> numpy.stack(2*i for i in range(10))
array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18])
```

Note that `numpy.stack` is internally consuming the generator and creating an intermediate list with `arrays = [asanyarray(arr) for arr in arrays]`. The implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/shape_base.py).

**[WARNING]**
As pointed out by @Joseh Seedy, Numpy 1.16 raises a warning that defeats usage of such function with generators.

Comment: This is a neat solution, thanks for pointing out.  But it seems to be quite a bit slower (in my application) than using `np.array(tuple(mygen))`. Here are the test results: `%timeit np.stack(permutations(range(10), 7)) 1 loop, best of 3: 1.9 s per loop` compared to `%timeit np.array(tuple(permutations(range(10), 7))) 1 loop, best of 3: 427 ms per loop`

Comment: This seems great and works for me. But with Numpy 1.16.1 I get this warning: `FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type such as list or tuple. Support for non-sequence iterables such as generators is deprecated as of NumPy 1.16 and will raise an error in the future.`

Comment: Still 7x faster than the accepted answer, even if you put a `list()` around the generator, according to my comparison with a 20,000 x 20,000 matrix.

Comment: In numpy 1.21.2 on an old imac, `time np.array( list( np.ndindex( 1000, 1000 )))  # CPU times: user 1.43 s`  `time np.stack( list( np.ndindex( 1000, 1000 )))  # CPU times: user 3.42 s`

Answer (score 6):

Somewhat tangential, but if your generator is a list comprehension, you can use `numpy.where` to more effectively get your result (I discovered this in my own code after seeing this post)

Answer (score 1):

The [vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html), [hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html), and [dstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) functions can take as input generators that yield multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Can you give an example in case the links change or something? :)

Comment: These functions can take a generator of arrays, not a generator of values

Comment: This is also deprecated in NumPy 1.16.