# Create a numpy matrix with elements as a function of indices

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

How can I create a numpy matrix with its elements being a function of its indices?
For example, a multiplication table: `a[i,j] = i*j`

An Un-numpy and un-pythonic would be to create an array of zeros and then loop through.

There is no doubt that there is a better way to do this, without a loop.

However, even better would be to create the matrix straight-away.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A generic solution would be to use [np.fromfunction()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html)

From the doc:

> `numpy.fromfunction(function, shape, **kwargs)`
>
> Construct an array by executing a function over each coordinate. The
> resulting array therefore has a value fn(x, y, z) at coordinate (x, y,
> z).

The below snippet should provide the required matrix.

```
import numpy as np

np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: i*j, (5,5))
```

Output:

```
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [  0.,   2.,   4.,   6.,   8.],
       [  0.,   3.,   6.,   9.,  12.],
       [  0.,   4.,   8.,  12.,  16.]])
```

The first parameter to the function is a callable which is executed for each of the coordinates. If `foo` is a function that you pass as the first argument, `foo(i,j)` will be the value at `(i,j)`. This holds for higher dimensions too. The shape of the coordinate array can be modified using the `shape` parameter.

**Edit:**

Based on the comment on using custom functions like `lambda x,y: 2*x if x > y else y/2`, the following code works:

```
import numpy as np

def generic_f(shape, elementwise_f):
    fv = np.vectorize(elementwise_f)
    return np.fromfunction(fv, shape)


def elementwise_f(x , y):
    return 2*x if x > y else y/2

print(generic_f( (5,5), elementwise_f))
```

Output:

```
[[0.  0.5 1.  1.5 2. ]
 [2.  0.5 1.  1.5 2. ]
 [4.  4.  1.  1.5 2. ]
 [6.  6.  6.  1.5 2. ]
 [8.  8.  8.  8.  2. ]]
```

The user is expected to pass a scalar function that defines the elementwise operation. [np.vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html#numpy-vectorize) is used to vectorize the user-defined scalar function and is passed to np.fromfunction().

Comment: This doesn't work with functions that involve complicated operations/logic. That's because `numpy` doesn't invoke your function for each coordinate but rather passes in the x and y coordinates as arrays just one time. For instance, if you wanted to construct a matrix using the function: `lambda x,y: 2*x if x > y else y/2`. Is it true that the naive method is the only alternative in this case?

Comment: @AdityaSriram, You can use the function that you would use with the naive method as the callable. But yeah, then the only advantage of `fromfunction()` is that it will be generating the indices list instead of the user explicitly generating it.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way to do that:

```
>>> indices = numpy.indices((5, 5))
>>> a = indices[0] * indices[1]
>>> a
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12],
       [ 0,  4,  8, 12, 16]])
```

To further explain, `numpy.indices((5, 5))` generates two arrays containing the x and y indices of a 5x5 array like so:

```
>>> numpy.indices((5, 5))
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]])
```

When you multiply these two arrays, numpy multiplies the value of the two arrays at each position and returns the result.

Comment: Is that generalizable for  a[i,j] = f(i,j)?

Comment: It is, if the expression for `f` is vectorized.

Answer (score 4):

For the multiplication

```
np.multiply.outer(np.arange(5), np.arange(5))  # a_ij = i * j
```

and in general

```
np.frompyfunc(
    lambda i, j: f(i, j), 2, 1
).outer(
    np.arange(5),
    np.arange(5),
).astype(np.float64)  # a_ij = f(i, j)
```

basically you create an `np.ufunc` via `np.frompyfunc` and then `outer` it with the indices.

### Edit

Speed comparision between the different solutions.

Small matrices:

```
Eyy![1]: %timeit np.multiply.outer(np.arange(5), np.arange(5))
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.97 µs per loop

Eyy![2]: %timeit np.array( [ [ i*j for j in xrange(5)] for i in xrange(5)] )
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.51 µs per loop

Eyy![3]: %timeit indices = np.indices((5, 5)); indices[0] * indices[1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.1 µs per loop
```

Bigger matrices:

```
Eyy![4]: %timeit np.multiply.outer(np.arange(4096), np.arange(4096))
10 loops, best of 3: 62.4 ms per loop

Eyy![5]: %timeit indices = np.indices((4096, 4096)); indices[0] * indices[1]
10 loops, best of 3: 165 ms per loop

Eyy![6]: %timeit np.array( [ [ i*j for j in xrange(4096)] for i in xrange(4096)] )
1 loops, best of 3: 1.39 s per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm away from my python at the moment, but does this one work?

```
array( [ [ i*j for j in xrange(5)] for i in xrange(5)] )
```

Comment: It sure does... array() is deceptively powerful!

Comment: Note that if you use this you have to be careful not to do ``np.array(( ( i*j for j in xrange(4096)) for i in xrange(4096)) )`` for which the result is unexpected. http://jim-holmstroem.github.io/numpy/2014/11/23/numpy-sum-over-iterator.html

Comment: Jim, I'm having trouble making sense of your link.  I think you're warning against passing generator expressions in to numpy? http://stackoverflow.com/q/367565/770038 covers that too.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add that @Senderle's response can be generalized for any function and dimension:

```
dims = (3,3,3) #i,j,k
ii = np.indices(dims)
```

You could then calculate `a[i,j,k] = i*j*k` as

```
a = np.prod(ii,axis=0)
```

or `a[i,j,k] = (i-1)*j*k`:

```
a = (ii[0,...]-1)*ii[1,...]*ii[2,...]
```

etc