# Vectorized assignment of a 2-dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I work with Python 2.7, numpy and pandas.

I have :

- a function y=f(x) where both x and y are **scalars**.
- a one-dimensional array of scalars of length n : [x0, x1, ..., x(n-1)]

I need to construct a 2-dimensional array D[i,j]=f(xi)*f(xj) where i,j are indices in [0,...,n-1].

I could use loops and/or a comprehension list, but that would be slow. I would like to use a vectorized approach instead.

I thought that "numpy.indices" would help me (see [Create a numpy matrix with elements a function of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254713/create-a-numpy-matrix-with-elements-a-function-of-indices)), but I admit I am at a loss on how to use that command for my purpose.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you really need to show an example of input and output here

Comment: For example, do `i` and `j` range over all indices, or are there specific ones you want?

Comment: This sounds like basic broadcasting to me. `x[None,:] * y[:,None]`. But we need to know more about `f` to give a good answer.

Comment: i and j range over every value in [0,1,...,n-1] so D is a square matrix with n rows and n columns. f() is a real scalar function. We can use exp(.) as an example. My f() is different, but I don't think it matters

Comment: @Charles the point is your function might be vectorizable.

Comment: Yeah, e.g. if `def f(x): return np.exp(x)` is your function, then `y = f(x); D = y * y[:,None]` should work, but if it were `math.exp(x)` then it wouldn't.

Comment: Ah yes I see. Let me reformulate the problem so that it is more prone to be vectorizable (perhaps). f is in fact a on-dimensional array of length n, so my problem is really to construct a square matrix with elements D[i,j]=f[i]*f[j], where i and j range over [0,...,n-1] - sorry if I was not clear before

Comment: @Charles That makes a significant difference, see my edited answer.

Comment: senderle's suggestion does the trick : D=f[None,:]*f[None,:] works. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to use a vectorized approach instead.

You sound like you might be a Matlab user -- you should be aware that [numpy's `vectorize` function provides no performance benefit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for
>   performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

Unless it just so happens that there's already an operation in `numpy` that does exactly what you want, you're going to be stuck with `numpy.vectorize` and nothing to really gain over a `for` loop. With that being said, you should be able to do that like so:

```
def makeArray():
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    def addTo(arr):
        return f(a[math.floor(arr/4)]) * f(a[arr % 4])
    vecAdd = numpy.vectorize(addTo)
    return vecAdd(numpy.arange(4 * 4).reshape(4, 4))
```

EDIT:

If `f` is actually a one-dimensional array, you can do this:

```
f_matrix = numpy.matrix(f)
D = f_matrix.T * f_matrix
```

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. Very useful.

Comment: Saying "numpy's vectorized operations provide no performance benefit" is very misleading. Using the `vectorize` **function** doesn't provide any.  But in numpy jargon, we say than an operation is vectorized if it doesn't use Python loops, e.g. `x**0.5+np.sin(x)`.

Comment: @DSM You're right, I edited my response to make that clearer. My point was more to suggest that, for an arbitrary function `f`, it's unlikely that you can get what you want from `numpy`. Tell me if you think my answer is still unclear.

Comment: Almost any arbitrary function can be rewritten to take advantage of vectorization in numpy: if you can write it in Python, the you can very likely write it in numpy.

Comment: @Jaime What about something like `def f(): return len(requests.get('http://www.google.com').text)`? Or `def f(): print "Hello World"; return 5`? Or `def  f(): return hashlib.md5(open('hello.txt').read())`? The majority of Python functions are not operations in linear algebra, and so the majority do not have an easy `numpy` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the comments that dismiss vectorization; it's a good habit to have, and it does deliver performance with the right accelerators. Anyway, what I really wanted to say was that you want to find the [outer product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product):

```
x_ = numpy.array(x)
y = f(x_)
numpy.outer(y, y)
```

If you're working with numbers you should be working with numpy data structures anyway. Then you get fast, readable code like this.

Comment: You're welcome. If you found the answers helpful you're encouraged to vote them up.

Comment: I Will but i dont have enough réputation points yet ! Still new to all This.. thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fromfunc to vectorize the function then use the dot product to multiply:

```
f2 = numpy.fromfunc(f, 1, 1)  # vectorize the function
res1 = f2(x)  # get the results for f(x)
res1 = res1[np.newaxis]  # result has to be 2D for the next step
res2 = np.dot(a.T, a)  # get f(xi)*f(xj)
```