# 2D array with different equation for each element

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, matrix

I'm relatively new to Python and designing scripts/simulations solo. I'm working on a simulation that involves a complex of parameters. There are four sets that exist in 200x50 matrices and other than the first row and first column, every other element in each matrix uses a different (allbeit related) equation to calculate its value. The general equation is:
`lambda_*((dfA[i-1,j-1]-(2*dfA[i-1,j])+dfA[i-1,j+1])+[dfA[i-1,j]])`, where dfA is shorthand for a pandas DataFrame using `.iloc`, e.g. `dfA = df_c_ox_A.iloc` `df_c_ox_A = pd.DataFrame(data)`. Naming convention seems weird but there are a lot of parameters.

As there are 10000x4 equations to write is there a faster way I can do this using loops. I know this code is wrong but this will hopefully show what I'm looking for:

```
for dfA[i,j] in range(200):
    if i == 0:
        dfA[i,j] = c_ox_b
    elif j == 0:
        dfA[i,j] = c_ox_0[i]
    for i >= 1 & j >= 1:
        dfA[i,j] = lambda_*((dfA[i-1,j-1]-(2*dfA[i-1,j])+dfA[i-1,j+1])+[dfA[i-1,j]])
```

For extra context, `c_ox_b` is a single value variable and `c_ox_0` is an array of values (200). It's chemistry based so I won't bore with the details.

Comment: A numpy matrix might be more natural than a pandas dataframe. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6254713/4996248) for how to construct a matrix where the elements are functions of its index. You could construct the first row and first column separately, and then glue it all together (or, wrap the logic into a single function which conditionally decided what to return)

Comment: Thanks, while testing if I'd put the DataFrame together properly I set the first row and first column so I know that works well. I'll look at the numpy matrix and try that.