# Slice Array Given Range from another array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

To be more clear, let me reword my question that I initially asked below.

I have a series of data points that rise and fall in amplitude as someone takes a step and then another step.  Zero is when the foot is off the ground.

A simple example would look like this:

```
 data_array = (0,0,0,10,20,50,40,30,10,0,0,0,0,0,10,20,50,40,30,10,0,0)
```

I determine when each step starts and stop by recording the starts (all the indexes that start) in one array and the stops in another array.

starts = (4  15)

stops = (9  20)

THE QUESTION:  Now, I want to slice the actual data for each step out of the initial array and them in columns.

[Note:  That, if necessary, we know the number of steps taken by the amount of data in the starts or stops arrays.]

10  10

20   20

50   50

40   40

30   30

10   10

I can not figure out how to use those starts and stops indices to slice the initial array. OR, I did not find a filter function to slice out the steps.

**BTW (2nd Edit)**
Here is some of the code I am using if it helps:

```
sigma = 5

threshold = 30

above_threshold = gaussian_filter(Fz, sigma=sigma) > threshold

#---INDEX ALL STATE CHANGES---

ind = np.where(np.diff(above_threshold))[0] + 1

print ind
```

***ORIGINAL QUESTION***

In this type of array:

```
data_array = (0,0,0,10,20,50,40,30,10,0,0)
```

I determine when values are above 20 and below 20.  I return those indexes as starts (going above 20) and stops (going below 20) by making the following:

```
startstop = np.vstack((ind[::2], ind[1::2])).T   
starts1=np.vstack((ind[::2])).T
stops1=np.vstack((ind[1::2])).T
```

Can someone point me in the right direction using numpy (or not) so that I can extract all those values in data_array using one of these arrays (startstop, starts1, stops1) to get this:

```
new_array = (50,40,30)
```

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python lists are defined with square brackets, and we want to generate a list of lists (where each piece contains one of your defined segments). Since computers start counting at 0, your "4th element is the start" translates to array index = 3.

One quirk is that to query the 4th to 9th element we'd use data_array[3:9]: this slice notation gives you every element starting at the first specified, up to (but not including) the last. The rest is a list comprehension that goes over any arbitrary number of step segments.

```
starts = [4, 15]
stops = [9, 20]
data_array = [0,0,0,10,20,50,40,30,10,0,0,0,0,0,10,20,50,40,30,10,0,0]
segments = [ data_array[starts[i] - 1: stops[i]  ]  for i in range( len(starts) ) ]
```

returns

```
>>> segments
[[10, 20, 50, 40, 30, 10], [10, 20, 50, 40, 30, 10]]
```

Each set of steps (segment) can be accessed individually:

```
>>>segments[0]
[10, 20, 50, 40, 30, 10]
```

EDIT: Alternately... if you need to use numpy array, then try:
    segments = array([ data_array[starts[i] - 1: stops[i]  ]  for i in range( len(starts) ) ])

I tried working in additional modules to get the array directly (using `itertools.islice` with `itertools.chain`, `numpy.fromiter`, etc). But even if the fancier solution worked, I'm not sure it'd offer significant speed advantages over converting to an array, and it would be a lot less concise. See: [How do I build a numpy array from a generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367565/how-do-i-build-a-numpy-array-from-a-generator)

Comment: This works if I flatter my numpy array into a 1D list.  But, then I'll have to rebuild new numpy arrays to take advantage of mathematical functions to run on each segment.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Depending on the size of your data, you might be able to get away with converting it to an array at the end: segments = array [ list comprehension ] ). Alternately, you could get a bit fancy and combine additional features/modules. I'll edit my post to include an alternate solution using numpy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the way you are trying to go about it, but can you use [filter](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter)?:

```
>>> data_array = (0,0,0,10,20,50,40,30,10,0)
>>> filter(lambda x: x>20,data_array)

(50, 40, 30)
```

Works with numpy arrays too.

Comment: Filter is appealing now.  I am currently using

sigma = 5                                                           threshold = 30                                                      above_threshold = gaussian_filter(Fz, sigma=sigma) > threshold      #arrray with True/Falso pending values above/below filter

#---INDEX ALL STATE CHANGES---
ind = np.where(np.diff(above_threshold))[0] + 1
print ind

Comment: Sorry, new to stackoverflow, not sure how to format my reply better. hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

take() will do what you wants, i think.

```
data_array = np.array([0,0,0,10,20,50,40,30,10,0])


b = data_array.take([1,2,3])
print b
```

output:

```
[ 0  0 10]
```

read more: [take()](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#take)
[more on take](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html)

Comment: Thanks, take may come in handy later.  But, I need to automate this one, not enter 1,2,3.

Comment: You can replace the array [1,2,3]. with an array you made that has the indexes of the elements you want. as this: b = data_array.take(starts1) . Thought that was your question?

Comment: starts1 only contains the starting index (one element), i have the end of the range in stops1.  I could make a new array with all the indexes between each start and stop.  Then pass them in.  Seems expensive though?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not perfectly clear, but if you are asking how to slice a Python list or iterable, use the built-in [slice function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#slice):

```
>>> data_array = (0,0,0,10,20,50,40,30,10,0)
>>> data_array[slice(5,8)]
(50, 40, 30)
>>> new_list=list(data_array[slice(5,8)])
>>> new_list
[50, 40, 30]
```

Comment: I reworded my question above.  You are right, not very clear.  Could I use your suggestion without putting in the 5, 8.  I tried that previously, but could not pass in variables to automate the code and to take out multiple slices.

Comment: @Scott: well, yes. You can do `data_array[slice(start,stop)]` and the slice built-in is less picky than the slice syntax of `l[8:10]` as an example.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.  Seems my major issue was that I was really trying to keep everything in a 2D numpy array that initially had the data.  I flattened it into a list and works.  But, I'll want to rebuild the numpy arrays for math done on each segment.