# How to Convert a 2D List of Tuples to a 3D Numpy Array Quickly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a stream of images coming in from a source which is, unfortunately a list of list of tuples of RGB values. I want to perform real-time processing on the image, but that code expects a Numpy array of shape (X,Y,3) where X and Y are the image height and width.

```
X = [[(R, G, B)...]]
img_arr = np.array([*X])
```

The above works fine but takes nearly a quarter of a second with my images which is obviously too slow. Interestingly, I also need to go back the other direction after the processing is done, and that code (which seems to work) is not so slow:

```
imgout = map(tuple, flipped_image)
```

Some relevant other questions:

[why is converting a long 2D list to numpy array so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973507/why-is-converting-a-long-2d-list-to-numpy-array-so-slow)

[Convert List of List of Tuples Into 2d Numpy Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806259/convert-list-of-list-of-tuples-into-2d-numpy-array)

Comment: Did you check what `imgout` is?  Is it really a list of tuples?  or just a `map` object?  For the original conversion what does `np.array(X)` do?

Comment: `imgout = map(tuple, flipped_image)` seems fast because it's not actually doing what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the title of your question, numpy automatically lists *and* tuples to numpy arrays, so you can just use `np.array(X)`, which will be about as fast as you can get:

```
img_arr = np.array(X)
```

A simple list comprehension will convert it back to the list-list-tuple form:

```
imgout = [[tuple(Z) for Z in Y] for Y in img_arr]
```

Code to generate a sample 10x10 `X` array:

```
X = [[tuple(Z) for Z in Y] for Y in np.random.randint(0,255,(10,10,3))]
```