# convert itertools array into numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I'm creating this array:

```
A=itertools.combinations(range(6),2)
```

and I have to manipulate this array with numpy, like:

```
A.reshape(..
```

If the dimensions is A is high, the command `list(A)` is too slow.

### How can I "convert" an itertools array into a numpy array?

Update 1:
I've tried the solution of hpaulj, in this specific situation is a little bit slower, any idea?

```
start=time.clock()

A=it.combinations(range(495),3)
A=np.array(list(A))
print A

stop=time.clock()
print stop-start
start=time.clock()

A=np.fromiter(it.chain(*it.combinations(range(495),3)),dtype=int).reshape (-1,3)
print A

stop=time.clock()
print stop-start
```

Results:

```
[[  0   1   2]
 [  0   1   3]
 [  0   1   4]
 ..., 
 [491 492 494]
 [491 493 494]
 [492 493 494]]
10.323822
[[  0   1   2]
 [  0   1   3]
 [  0   1   4]
 ..., 
 [491 492 494]
 [491 493 494]
 [492 493 494]]
12.289898
```

Comment: Hello, where is  your question?

Comment: How can i "convert" an itertools array into a numpy array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367565/how-do-i-build-a-numpy-array-from-a-generator

Comment: Are you sure it's not "too slow" because the number of combinations is excessively large? If you're trying to create a billion elements or something, that's always going to take a while. The `itertools.combinations` call returns immediately because it doesn't actually create any of the combinations up front, it's a generator.

Answer (score 6):

I'm reopening this because I dislike the linked answer.  The accepted answer suggests using

```
np.array(list(A))  # producing a (15,2) array
```

But the OP aparently has already tried `list(A)`, and found it to be slow.

Another answer suggests using `np.fromiter`.  But buried in its comments is the note that `fromiter` requires a 1d array.

```
In [102]: A=itertools.combinations(range(6),2)
In [103]: np.fromiter(A,dtype=int)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-29db40e69c08> in <module>()
----> 1 np.fromiter(A,dtype=int)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

So using `fromiter` with this itertools requires somehow flattening the iterator.

A quick set of timings suggests that `list` isn't the slow step.  It's converting the list to an array that is slow:

```
In [104]: timeit itertools.combinations(range(6),2)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 µs per loop
In [105]: timeit list(itertools.combinations(range(6),2))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.1 µs per loop
In [106]: timeit np.array(list(itertools.combinations(range(6),2)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.7 µs per loop
```

I think the fastest way to use `fromiter` is to flatten the `combinations` with an idiomatic use of `itertools.chain`:

```
In [112]: timeit
np.fromiter(itertools.chain(*itertools.combinations(range(6),2)),dtype=int)
   .reshape(-1,2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.1 µs per loop
```

Not much of a time savings, at least on this small size.  (`fromiter` also takes a `count`, which shaves off another µs.  With a larger case, `range(60)`, the `fromiter` takes half the time of `array`.

---

A quick search on `[numpy] itertools` turns up a number of suggestions of pure numpy ways of generating all combinations.  `itertools` is fast, for generating pure Python structures, but converting those to arrays is a slow step.

---

A picky point about the question.

`A` is a generator, not an array.  `list(A)` does produce a nested list, that can be described loosely as an array.  But it isn't a `np.array`, and does not have a `reshape` method.

Comment: You can squeeze a bit more performance out of `np.fromiter` by specifying the size of the final array , which can be computed using `scipy.special.binom(6, 2)`

Comment: @hpaulj I've tried your solution, please see update in the question

Comment: There are pure numpy ways of generating combinations that may be faster.  @all_m suggests one using `triu`.  I believe others have been proposed in previous SO questions.

Comment: `A quick search on [numpy] itertools turns up a number of suggestions of pure numpy ways of generating all combinations.`

@hpaulj Would you mind linking some of those, cause I couldn't find any?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnumpy%5D+itertools

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way to get every pairwise combination of `N` elements is to generate the indices of the upper triangle of an `(N, N)` matrix using `np.triu_indices(N, k=1)`, e.g.:

```
np.vstack(np.triu_indices(6, k=1)).T
```

For small arrays, `itertools.combinations` is going to win, but for large *N* the `triu_indices` trick can be substantially quicker:

```
In [1]: %timeit np.fromiter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(range(6), 2)), np.int)
The slowest run took 10.46 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.04 µs per loop

In [2]: %timeit np.array(np.triu_indices(6, 1)).T
The slowest run took 10.97 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.3 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit np.fromiter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(range(1000), 2)), np.int)
10 loops, best of 3: 69.7 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit np.array(np.triu_indices(1000, 1)).T
100 loops, best of 3: 10.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: I think that solution doesn't generate more than combination of two elements

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it because your original question was about combinations of two elements. I think it may be possible to generalize this approach to deal with combinations of more than two elements, but would require a bit more thought.

Comment: I didn't know about the `chain.fromiterable`.  For large cases it's twice as fast as `chain(*...)`.

Comment: Great answer for my use case, 66-fold speedup for `np.array(np.triu_indices(1000, 1))` compared to my naive `np.array(tuple(zip(*itertools.combinations(range(1000), 2))))`, itself slightly faster than `np.array(tuple(itertools.combinations(range(1000), 2))).T`.