# How to replace For Loops and IF statements with Numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array like this:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], ...]
```

I would like to get the combinations of all "sub" arrays (i.e [X, Y]) three by three:

```
[[1, 1] [1, 1] [1, 1],
 [1, 1] [1, 1] [1, 2],
 [1, 1] [1, 1] [1, 3],
 ...
 [5, 5] [5, 5], [5, 4],
 [5, 5] [5, 5], [5, 5]]
```

Then, I need to apply conditions on each combinations:

- `X1, X2, X3 > 0`
- `X1+Y1 <= X2`
- `X2+Y2 <= X3`
- `[X1, Y1] =! [X2, Y2]`
- `[X2, Y2] =! [X3, Y3]`
- `...`

I absolutely need to avoid for loops because of the high number of combinations.

Any idea how to get this done in an effective time of execution?

---

My current code with for loops and if statements:

## The mylist object is like [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], ...] (i.e list of lists like [X, Y]).

Combination = []
for left in mylist:

```
    if left[0] > 0:
        
        for center in mylist:   
            
            if (center[0] > 0 
                and center[0] >= left[0] + left[1]
                and center[1] / left[1] < 2 
                and center[0] / left[0] < 2
                and left[1] / center[1] < 2 
                and left[0] / center[1] < 2 
                and str(left[0]) + "y" + str(left[1]) + "y" != str(center[0]) + "y" + str(center[1]) + "y"
                ):
            
                for right in mylist:   
        
                    if (right[0] > 0 
                        and right[0] >= center[0] + center[1]
                        and right[1] / center[1] < 2 
                        and right[0] / center[0] < 2
                        and center[1] / right[1] < 2 
                        and center[0] / right[0] < 2
                        and str(right[0]) + "y" + str(right[1]) + "y" != str(center[0]) + "y" + str(center[1]) + "y"
                        ):

                        Combination.append([[left[0], left[1]], [center[0], center[1]], [right[0], right[1]])
```

Comment: any code you have written so far?

Comment: I edited my post to add the original code with for loops and if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** You don't even need `itertools` you can use `numpy` to create the combinations and it's extremely fast

```py
# This is your input array from [1,1] to [5,5]
a = np.array(np.meshgrid(np.arange(1,6), np.arange(1,6))).T.reshape(-1,2)

b = np.array(np.meshgrid(a, a, a)).T.reshape(-1, 3, 2)
```

As you can see it takes 6ms: `5.88 ms ± 836 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

Your array looks like this now:

```
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2]],

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 3]],

       ...,

       [[5, 5],
        [5, 5],
        [5, 3]],

       [[5, 5],
        [5, 5],
        [5, 4]],

       [[5, 5],
        [5, 5],
        [5, 5]]])
```

Because this is a numpy array now, you can safely use a for loop to check your conditions. For example `row[0,0]` would be your `X1` and `row[0,1]` would be your `Y1` etc.

```py
for row in b:
    row[0,0] + row[0,1] <= row[1,0]
```

This also takes a really short amount of time to execute: `10.3 ms ± 278 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

So you can safely do this for your other conditions aswell.

Comment: Mixing the Mashudan's and emilanov answers, I get exactly what I was looking for! Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try `itertool` and `numpy` like:

```py
import numpy as np
import itertools


some_list = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [-1,-1]]


# use "itertools.combinations" or "itertools.combinations_with_replacement"
# whatever you want to get in therms of repeting elements.
# Then cast it into a numpy array.
combinations = np.array(list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(some_list, 3)))


# from here your can do your boolean statements in the numpy sytax for example
# applying your first rule "X1,X2,X3 > 0" could be done with:
first_rule = combinations[:,:,0] > 0
print('boolean array for the first rule "X1,X2,X3 > 0"')
print(np.all(first_rule,axis=1))


# and the second rule "X1 + Y1 <= X2"
second_rule = combinations[:,0,0]+combinations[:,0,1] <= combinations[:,1,0]
print('\n\nboolean array for the first rule "X1 + Y1 <= X2"')
print(second_rule)
```

I assumed that its not just a regular grid because of the first condition X1,X2,X3 > 0, but yes if its regular then the meshgrid is the best solution (see the other answer).

Comment: Great solution for efficient application of conditions. For creating the combinations though, it would be better to use `np.meshgrid()` as [creating a numpy array from a python list is slow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282369/convert-itertools-array-into-numpy-array)

Comment: Very true but I am not sure if it is a regular grid and if so this has only have to applied once and then can be saved. But ofc `np.meshgird` is the far more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

`from itertools import product
a = [[1,1],[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]]
perms = np.array(list(product(a, repeat=3)))`
 
This will create an array of shape `(n^3, 3, 2)` where `n` is the number of elements in `a`.

Now you can do all your fancy operations...

```
perms[:, :, 0] > 0
perms[:, 0, 0] + perms[:, 0, 1] <= perms[:, 1, 0]
perms[:, 1, 0] + perms[:, 1, 1] <= perms[:, 2, 0]
perms[:, 0, :] != perms[:, 1, :]
perms[:, 1, :] != perms[:, 2, :]
...
```

note that the last two expression will check `x1!=x2` and `y1!=y2` **seperately** and return a result of shape **(n^3,2)**. However if your requirement is to check whether those instances are not equal as a whole you can just do

`output = perms[:, 0, :] != perms[:, 1, :]
np.logical_or(output[:, 0], output[:, 1])`

which will return the output with shape (n^3).