# Python - How to construct a numpy array out of a list of objects efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am building a python application where I retrieve a list of objects and I want to plot them (for ploting I use `matplotlib`). Each object in the list contains two properties.

For example let's say I have the list rawdata and the objects stored in it have the properties timestamp and power

```
rawdata[0].timestamp == 1
rawdata[1].timestamp == 2
rawdata[2].timestamp == 3
```

etc

```
rawdata[0].power == 1232.547
rawdata[1].power == 2525.423
rawdata[2].power == 1125.253
```

etc

I want to be able to plot those two dimensions, that the two properties represent, and I want to do it a time and space efficient way. That means that I want to avoid iterating over the list and sequentially constructing something like a numpy array out it.

Is there a way that to apply an on-the-fly transformation of the list? Or somehow plot it as it is? Since all the information is already included in the list I believe there should be a way.

The closest answer I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367565/how-do-i-build-a-numpy-array-from-a-generator), but it includes sequential iteration over the list.

**update**

As pointed out by Antonio Ragagnin I can use the `map` builtin function to construct a numpy array efficiently. But that also means that I will have to create a second data structure. Can I use `map` to transform the list on the fly to a two dimensional numpy array?

Comment: Is `map` builtin function (it is wrote in C inside Python interpreter) a good option for you?

Comment: that is indeed helpful, I should had map in mind before asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [matplotlib tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) (emphasis mine):

> If matplotlib were limited to working with lists, it would be fairly useless for numeric processing. Generally, you will use numpy arrays. **In fact, all sequences are converted to numpy arrays internally.**

So you lose nothing by converting it to a numpy array, if you don't do it matplotlib will.