# Extending a numpy array up to a specific range with its own content

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What is the most efficient way to extend an array with its own values up to a specific size?

```
import numpy as np

# For this example, lets use an array with 4 items
data = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11]]) # 4 items

# I want to extend it to 10 items, here's the expected result would be:
data = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2],
                 [ 3,  4,  5],
                 [ 6,  7,  8],
                 [ 9, 10, 11],
                 [ 0,  1,  2],
                 [ 3,  4,  5],
                 [ 6,  7,  8],
                 [ 9, 10, 11],
                 [ 0,  1,  2],
                 [ 3,  4,  5]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate arrays:

```
def extend_array(arr, length):
    factor, fraction = divmod(length, len(arr))
    return np.concatenate([arr] * factor + [arr[:fraction]])

>>> extend_array(data, 10)

array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5]])
```

Comment: Quick correction, you want `arr[:fraction]`. Depending on the size of the array, your method can be noticeably faster because the repeated whole *chunks* are intermediately stored as references to the same object.

Comment: awesome! yes the last item should be arr[:fraction]

Comment: Corrected. Changed the name and forgot one of them.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way I can think of is using the itertools module. First create a cycle of each row (infinite iterator) and then fetch as many rows as you need with [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). The result of this must be a tuple or list, because [numpy requires the length of the array to be explicit at construction time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367565/how-do-i-build-a-numpy-array-from-a-generator).

```
import itertools as it

def extend_array(arr, length):
    return np.array(tuple(it.islice(it.cycle(arr), length)))
```

Usage:

```
>>> data = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11]])
>>> extend_array(data, 10)
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5]])
```