# How to convert itertools.chain into numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My code

```
import math
import itertools

with open('/home/milenko/OCCAM2DMT_V3.0/13042/ITER04.iter') as f:
    lines_after_19 = f.readlines()[19:]
    p = []
    for line in lines_after_19:
        line = line.split()         
        line = [float(i) for i in line]
        p.extend(line)    

a1=p[1:81]
for i in a1:
    b1=math.pow(10, i)   
a2=p[83:163]
for i in a2:
    b2=math.pow(10,i)
a3=p[165:245]   
for i in a3:
    b3=math.pow(10,i)
a4=p[247:327]
for i in a4:
    b4=math.pow(10,i)
a5=p[329:409] 
for i in a5:
    b5=math.pow(10,i)
a6=p[411:491]
for i in a6:
    b6=math.pow(10,i)

c = itertools.chain(b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6) 
print type(c)
```

I need to convert c to `numpy` array,for `reshape` and then further calculations.

Comment: You've got a lot of problems here besides converting `c` to an array. `c` doesn't even contain the data you want, because those `for` loops aren't building `b1` through `b6` right. The best time to convert to numpy is right at the start of your program, when you load the data from the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was marked as duplicate with a reference to this: [How do I build a numpy array from a generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367565/how-do-i-build-a-numpy-array-from-a-generator) question.

The highest ranking answer, using `fromiter` is a good choice when dealing with a generator, but that doesn't really address the issue in this question.

As commented, the `for` loops don't save anything except the last calculation.  And they needlessly perform `math.pow` calculations that could just as well be done in `numpy`.

Skipping the `pow` bit for now:

```
In [36]: ll=range(100)
In [53]: a=ll[0:20]    
In [54]: b=ll[22:40]
In [55]: c=ll[42:60]
```

There are several ways I could combine these into a one array; first just a list.

```
In [56]: len(list(itertools.chain(a,b,c)))
Out[56]: 56
```

an array from that list

```
In [57]: np.array(list(itertools.chain(a,b,c)))
Out[57]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,...., 59])
```

`fromiter` is a bit faster;

```
In [58]: np.fromiter(itertools.chain(a,b,c),int)
Out[58]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5, ... 58, 59])
```

so is `concatenate` - it converts its inputs to arrays and concatenates them (default is flat):

```
In [59]: np.concatenate((a,b,c))
Out[59]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5, ... 52, 53, 54,
       55, 56, 57, 58, 59])
```

It's easy to perform the `pow` calculation on the array

```
In [62]: 10**(la/100.)
Out[62]: 
array([ 1.        ,  1.02329299,  1.04712855,  1.07151931,  1.0964782 ,
        1.12201845,  1.14815362,  1.17489755,  1.20226443,  1.23026877,
        ...
        3.4673685 ,  3.54813389,  3.63078055,  3.71535229,  3.80189396,
        3.89045145])
```

Since the numbers have been read in from a file, and are present in the list `p`, there isn't much point in trying to save memory by using a generator.  `chain` is useful here just as a way of creating a flat list.

If all lines in the file had the same number of items, it could have been loaded with a `np.loadtxt`.  The result would be a 2d array.

All your sublists are length 80.  Are there 81 numbers in each line, and you are skipping the first?  If so, the `loadtxt` array would be `(N,81)` in shape, and you could easily drop the 1st with slicing `[:, 1:]`.

---

Since all the lists that you chain are the same length you could have just passed those to `np.array` without chain.

```
 np.array((b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6))
```

would produce a `(6,80)` shaped array.  No need to `reshape` - unless you want a different one.