# Efficiently using Numpy to assign function values to array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am interested in finding the fastest way of carrying a simple operation in Python3.6 using Numpy. I wish to create a function and from a given array to an array of function values. Here is a simplified code that does that using `map`:

```
import numpy as np
def func(x):
    return x**2
xRange = np.arange(0,1,0.01)
arr_func = np.array(list(map(func, xRange)))
```

However, as I am running it with a complicated function and using large arrays, runtime speed is very important for me. Is there a known faster way?

**EDIT** My question is not the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367565/how-do-i-build-a-numpy-array-from-a-generator) one, because I am asking about assigning from a function, as opposed to a generator.

Comment: The actual implementation would involve specific optimizations. So, without seeing it, there's no magical way for generic cases.

Comment: Thank you @Divakar I am indeed looking for a a faster way to deal with generic cases.

Comment: Why xRange and pRange? In this particular case, the **2 operation is aleady vectorized so you're incurring in a penalty by doing the map instead of just doing `arr_func = func(xRange)`. In general cases, you have to try and exploit as much as you can vectorized operations.

Comment: Thanks @IgnacioVergaraKausel, the `pRange` was an error in pasting. I removed it.

Comment: Just to add, if you just did `func(xRange)` i get a 44.8 micro second while your map to list to array takes 33.4 milli seconds (for an array of 100000 random elements).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I build a numpy array from a generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367565/how-do-i-build-a-numpy-array-from-a-generator)

Comment: `fromiter`` and `frompyfunc` are possible alternatives.  You may have to do some timings of your own.  The time spent running your function might dominate any iteration and collection mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the related [How do I build a numpy array from a generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/367565/37020), where the most compelling option seems to be preallocating the numpy array and setting values, instead of creating a throwaway intermediate list.

```
arr_func = np.empty(len(xRange))
for i in range(len(xRange)):
  arr_func[i] = func(xRange[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

With a complex function that can't be rewritten with compiled `numpy` functions, we can't make big improvements in speed.

Define a function with `math` methods that require scalars, for example:

```
def func(x):
    return math.sin(x)**2 + math.cos(x)**2

In [868]: x = np.linspace(0,np.pi,10000)
```

For reference do a straight forward list comprehension:

```
In [869]: np.array([func(i) for i in x])
Out[869]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.])

In [870]: timeit np.array([func(i) for i in x])
13.4 ms ± 211 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Your list map is slightly faster:

```
In [871]: timeit np.array(list(map(func, x)))
12.6 ms ± 12.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

For 1d array like this, `np.array` can be replaced with `np.fromiter`.  It works with a generator as well, including the Py3 `map`.

```
In [875]: timeit np.fromiter(map(func, x),float)
13.1 ms ± 176 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So that could get around the possible time penalty of creating a whole list first.  But in this case it doesn't help.

Another iterator is `np.frompyfunc`.  It is used by `np.vectorize`, but usually is faster with less overhead.  It returns a dtype object array:

```
In [876]: f = np.frompyfunc(func, 1, 1)
In [877]: f(x)
Out[877]: array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, ..., 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], dtype=object)
In [878]: timeit f(x)
11.1 ms ± 298 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [879]: timeit f(x).astype(float)
11.2 ms ± 85.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

A slight speed improvement.  I noticed more of an improvement with 1000 item `x`.  This is even better if your problem requires several arrays that may be broadcasted against each other.

Assigning to a preallocated `out` array may save memory, and is often recommended as a alternative to the list append iteration.  But here it doesn't not give a speed improvement:

```
In [882]: %%timeit 
     ...: out = np.empty_like(x)
     ...: for i,j in enumerate(x): out[i]=func(j)
16.1 ms ± 308 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

(the use of `enumerate` is slightly faster than `range` iteration).