# TensorFlow 1.7 + Keras and datasets: Object has no attribute 'ndim'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am getting the following error when calling keras `model.fit()`.

`AttributeError: 'RepeatDataset' object has no attribute 'ndim'`

I am using TensorFlow 1.7 and Keras.  Unfortunately, **I must use TF 1.7**.  Any idea what's going on?  The code, *adapted* from a tensorflow demo:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from IPython import embed
from tensorflow.python import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(32,), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001),
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'])

import numpy as np

# Generate random data using numpy
def random_one_hot_labels(shape):
    n, n_class = shape
    classes = np.random.randint(0, n_class, n)
    labels = np.zeros((n, n_class))
    labels[np.arange(n), classes] = 1
    return labels

data = np.random.random((1000, 32))
labels = random_one_hot_labels((1000, 10))

datasetA = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, labels))
datasetB = datasetA.batch(32)
dataset = datasetB.repeat()

model.fit(
    dataset, 
    epochs=10,
    steps_per_epoch=30
)
```

Comment: Can you try passing parameters to `repeat()` as `repeat(count=2)`

Comment: Also, can you great the batches after creating the `repeat()`

Comment: Remove `datasetB = datasetA.batch(32)` and add `dataset = datasetA.repeat(<epochs>).batch(32)`

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa  Thanks for the ideas.  No, they give the same error (again using TF 1.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error arises because `repeat()` is returning a generator, which you are passing to `fit`. `fit` expects a numpy array which has a defined `ndim`. Support for generators with `fit` was added later on. Try using the now deprecated [`fit_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit_generator) instead:

```
model.fit_generator(
    dataset, 
    epochs=10,
    steps_per_epoch=30
)
```

Also note that without any arguments, `repeat()` will use `-1`, which may or may not be the behavior you are looking for. Something like `repeat(1)` or `repeat(2)` is probably what you're looking for. Source for `RepeatDataset` as of release `1.7`:

```
class RepeatDataset(Dataset):
  """A `Dataset` that repeats its input several times."""

  def __init__(self, input_dataset, count):
    """See `Dataset.repeat()` for details."""
    super(RepeatDataset, self).__init__()
    self._input_dataset = input_dataset
    if count is None:
      self._count = constant_op.constant(-1, dtype=dtypes.int64, name="count")
    else:
      self._count = ops.convert_to_tensor(
          count, dtype=dtypes.int64, name="count")
```

I tried reproducing it, but it'll take me a little more effort to be able to get the right version installed.

If that doesn't work, it may be worth it to try to manually iterate through your dataset generator and create a numpy array from it first, then pass that to `fit`. I'm not sure if there's a Keras way of doing this in `1.7`, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367565/how-do-i-build-a-numpy-array-from-a-generator) might be useful if you have to go down that route.