# Insert 1D array into a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, insert, python-itertools

I am trying to insert a column into a 2D array.
Currently I have a 2D array generated using itertools.

```
sample_points=[-1.5, -.8]
base_points = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(sample_points, 3)
base_points_list=list(base_points)
base_points_array=np.asarray(base_points_list)
```

Then I get an array which looks like this:

```
>>> base_points_array
array([[-1.5, -1.5, -1.5],
       [-1.5, -1.5, -0.8],
       [-1.5, -0.8, -0.8],
       [-0.8, -0.8, -0.8]])
```

I want to add a column at the beginning so that the array looks like this:

```
[[1 -1.5 -1.5 -1.5]
 [1 -1.5 -1.5 -0.8]
 [1 -1.5 -0.8 -0.8]
 [1 -0.8 -0.8 -0.8]]
```

So I used the command:
np.insert(base_points_array,0,1,1)
Because it should be able to do that using broadcasting.
but I get something completely different. the number of rows have changes:

```
array([[ 1. , -1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -0.8],
       [ 1. , -1.5, -1.5, -0.8, -0.8],
       [ 1. , -1.5, -0.8, -0.8, -0.8]])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No repro. Got expected result.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. When I try `np.insert(base_points_array,0,1,1)`, I get the expected result, and not the claimed result. Do keep in mind that `np.insert` creates a new array and does not modify the original.

Comment: Executing `np.insert(base_points_array.T,0,1,1)` gives the result you see.  Any chance you accidentally transposed your array in between creating it and doing the `insert`?

Comment: Agreed, it looks as though the array somehow got transposed first. As a side note, it isn't necessary to make a temporary list: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367565/how-do-i-build-a-numpy-array-from-a-generator

Comment: I don't know. Now it is somehow working what I suggested.

Comment: I just realized, that I indeed did a transpose on the array before inserting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `np.append` . But if your array to insert is 1D array

`insert_array= [1, 1, 1, 1]`

You need to expand the dimension of your inserting array by 1 first, you can do it with

`insert_array= np.expand_dims(insert_array, 1)`

And then you can use the append method

`base_points_array= np.append(insert_array, base_points_array, 1)`

Comment: I intially gave an up arrow for the answer. but then I realized, that it didn't work somehow. So wanted to cancel the up arrow and clicked on the down arrow, although I didn't want to give a down arrow. I am really sorry about that. Is there a way I can remove the downvote?

Comment: @eeqesri It didnt work for you? maybe because you did not assign the np.append() to a new array, since it does not modify the array but make a new array instead.

Comment: Indeed you are right. It worked now after saving it in a new array and then printing it.

Comment: @eeqesri all right, that is actually my bad for not give a detailed answer, ill edit it